# ember js, continuously invoke init method in controller when user visit page

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-components, ember-controllers

i have a controller script in ember and iam using init() method in controller. 
this is my script

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
.....,
init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('idUser', this.commonService.getUser().id);
    Ember.$(document).ready(function () {
      let height = Ember.$(window).height() - 96;
      Ember.$(".feed-activity-list").slimScroll({
        height: height.toString() + "px"
      });
    });
  },
})
```

the init method is invoke when user first time open the page. but when user open another page and back to this page, the controller doesnt invoke the init() method.
how to force the controller run init method when user visit this page. Iam avoid using component because its hard to refactor :(

Answer (score 4):

Controller is singleton so only one time `init` will be called. You can make use of the corresponding route `activate` hook or `didTransition` hook. but its not guaranteed by that time DOM is ready. you might need to use `Ember.run.next` or `Ember.run.later('afterRender', () => { })`.
Use `component`  that is the ember best practise.